# Google Maps JS gets cropped on download html2canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html2canvas

So the image that I donwload gets cropped. The canvas size is the same as the screen but the content doesn't get loaded fully.

```js
captureScreenshot(): void {
    let x = document.getElementById('map');
    if (x) {
      const canvasWidth = x.clientWidth; 
      const canvasHeight = x.clientHeight; 
      html2canvas(x, {
        useCORS: true,
        width: canvasWidth,
        height: canvasHeight
      }).then((canvas) => {
        const image64 = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
        
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = image64; 
        link.download = 'screenshot.jpg'; 

        link.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));
      });
    }
  }
```

The result is the follwing:

[image]